# Android: Get the listview item from button clicked in custom listview

Tags: android, arrays, listview, view, android-arrayadapter

I have a custom ListView with two button and I when I click either button on any row I want to get the text label on the Listview and for now just popup a toast with it. So far nothing has worked I keep getting the last item in my array.

Here is a screen shot to give you a better idea of what i mean

[image]

Here is my Adapter subclass for my custom ListView

```
static final String[] Names = 
           new String[] { "John", "Mike", "Maria", "Miguel"};


class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private final Context context;      

    int which;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] pValues) {
        super(context, R.layout.main, pValues);
        this.context = context;
        values = pValues;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.logo);
        Button call = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button chat = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        textView.setText(values[position]);


        // Change icon based on name
        s = values[position];           
        which = position;
        call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String name = values[which];
                Toast.makeText(CustomListView.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
String name = textView.getText().toString();
RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout)v.getParent();
textView = (TextView)ll.findViewById(R.id.label);
Toast.makeText(CustomListView.this, name,
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: try `textView.getText().toString()` in place of `values[which]`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Easy to do:

```
    call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)v.getParent();
            TextView tv = (TextView)rl.findViewById(R.id.label);
            String text = tv.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(CustomListView.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        } 
    });
```

Comment: I used a Relative Layout in my XML. I have done this and there are some improvements but the first time I click on each button I get the value of the previous TextView after which I get the correct values.

I also get a warning in Logcat : 06-22 14:28:29.279: W/Resources(14841): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f050002}

Comment: That shouldn't happen since the above code uses the button clicked to find the parent (row) and then uses that to find the sibling textview...  could you edit your post to show the code as it is now?

Comment: I've edited my post now. I'm surprised as well because I believe it should work.

Comment: Oh dear I think I used should have the get text below the getparent

Comment: This is alot simpler to implement

Answer (score 5):

use setTag attribute of the View..............

as

```
Button call = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
call.setTag(position);
```

and

```
call.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               int which = -1;
               Obejct obj =  v.getTag();
              if(obj instaceof Integer){
               which  = ((Integer)obj).intValue();
                    }

              if(which >-1){
                String name = values[which];
                Toast.makeText(CustomListView.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Wow, this worked. Can you please briefly explain what exactly you are doing

Comment: basically every view has capable to keeping  any object using setTag I just set the position in tag with each button at that row and when you get View in onClick (which is same button) I just get back the tag from that particular button.........

Answer (score 2):

If you have a ListActivity, and you're not using your own adapter, you can still get the list item belonging to the tapped button, like so:

In your layout file of the list row:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button_call"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:contentDescription="Call"
        android:onClick="callBuddy"
        android:src="@drawable/call_button_image"
        />
```

In your ListActivity:

```
public void callBuddy(View view) {

    int position = getListView().getPositionForView((View) view.getParent());
    Buddy buddyToCall = (Buddy) getListView().getItemAtPosition(position);

    Toast.makeText(MyListActivity.this, String.format("Calling your buddy %s.", buddyToCall.name), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set onClick="click" to xml of button/image/etc...

and in your Activity, do:

```
public void click(View v) {
    final int position = getListView().getPositionForView(v);
    String text = getListView().getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Wow this seems so simple.You wont have to define anything else?Like what is `getListView()` or `position`

Comment: final int position = getListView().getPositionForView(v);

Answer (score 0):

simply use getItem() and pass the  position
Ex:`getItem(position).getID()`
here getID() method is getter method