# Android:Get button clicked in custom listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-custom-view, android-adapter

I have used LazyAdapter for creating a custom listview. Now I require to use an image which can be clicked to dial a number. The error is coming in the onclick method of the image. StartActivity says "there is no such method in LazyAdapter". I am posting the code below.

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private String[] data;
private String[] project;

Context con;

public LazyAdapter(Context con) {
    this.con = con;
}


public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] pic, String[] p) {
    activity = a;
    data = pic;
    project = p;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) con
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View vi = convertView;

    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_result_page, null);



    ------more code----
    ImageView ivCall = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.imageViewIRCall);
    ivCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String uri = "tel:9818222333";
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
             intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
             startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    return vi;
}
```

I have already refered this link but the error is there in startActivity.
[SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156078/android-get-the-listview-item-from-button-clicked-in-custom-listview)

Comment: how can the code compile when there is error in onclick method. I am even not able to show a toast. Maketext method says rename.

Comment: use con.startActivity(intent);

Comment: thanks @Manishika corrent answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you need to append context of activity while calling intent!

Within Onclick@

**Use#**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
             intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
             activity.startActivity(intent);
```

**Instead#**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
             intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
             startActivity(intent);
```

**Additionally#**

Use ViewHoder inside `getView()` method and `set tag to button and get tag` inside onClick to get correct position of view.

Comment: can you also suggest something for performing load more functionality on this...like adding more and more elements when scrolling down the list.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

instead of

```
startActivity(intent);
```

and make sure you have permission for phone call in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```